# Binding Guid in Controller method in Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have controller method:

```
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    [Route("page/{session:guid}")]
    [HttpGet("page")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<DtoResult>> GetPageAsync(Guid session, int page = -1,  int pageSize = -1)
    {
            var result = await _paginationInfrastructure.GetDtos(session, page, pageSize, _reportManagerService);
            return Ok(result);
    }
```

Angular client http code:

```
getPage(sessionGuid: string, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number): Observable<ReportDtoResult> {
var paginationUrl = this.configService.getPaginationUrl();
var fullPaginationUrl = `${paginationUrl}`;
  
var paramsArgs = new HttpParams();
paramsArgs.set('session',sessionGuid);
paramsArgs.set('page',pageIndex);
paramsArgs.set('pageSize',pageSize);
return this.http.get<DtoResult>(fullPaginationUrl,{params:paramsArgs});
```

}

request via Swagger:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:5001/page/081B1B5A-9875-4813-B5ED-A131598B3FC4?page=-1&pageSize=-1" -H "accept: text/plain"
```

So, when send Guid string from client to server i get empty guid.
I try to make routing , but it not work for me.

How to make valid request?

P.S. the request must be:

```
var fullPaginationUrl = `${paginationUrl}/${sessionGuid}?page=${pageIndex}&pageSize=${pageSize}`;
```

And it works!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your route setup, it's with the way you're making the request in Angular.

You're adding the guid as a query parameter named `session`. What you need to do instead is to make it part of the path (as you've got configured).

So you request should look like the following:

```
...
var fullPaginationUrl = `${paginationUrl}/${sessionGuid}`;

var paramsArgs = new HttpParams();
paramsArgs.set('page', pageIndex);
paramsArgs.set('pageSize', pageSize);
...
```

The above assumes that `paginationUrl` is `https://localhost:5001/page`

The `session` in `[Route("page/{session:guid}")` is just specifying what the name of the parameter that you're mapping the guid to is in your action method